# Calling Coroutine functions from Java

Tags: java, kotlin, interop, kotlin-coroutines

I have written a small library for async testing in Kotlin with JUnit, which is based on coroutines with runBlocking scope. I would like to have at least some kind of interop with Java. My coroutine knowledge is limited, but my idea was that if I let Kotlin create the scope and only bridge suspend function calls in Java class, passing the Continuation created by Kotlin method to method it might work. Currently I have something like this construct

```
class AsyncTestLibrary {
    fun doSyncAction(){}
    suspend fun doAsyncAction(){}
}
// JAVA compatibility wrapper
fun runTest(lib: AsyncTestLibrary, testBody: suspend (lib: AsyncTestLibrary) -> Unit) =
    runBlocking {
        testBody(lib)
    }
```

And following usage in Java

```
@Test
public void test(){
    runTest(testLibraryInstance, (lib, continuation) -> {
        lib.doSyncAction();
        lib.doAsyncAction(continuation);

        return Unit.INSTANCE;
    });
}
```

Unfortunately this approach does not seem to be working, getting some strange behavior and classCastExceptions like `kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.CompletedContinuation cannot be cast to class kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuation`

Is there something fundamental about coroutines that means this will never work in general, or is there some interop library / approach I am missing?

Comment: Are you open to sharing the task to Java as a Future? There are extension functions that can do that. It would be a lot simpler to use. By the way, calling a suspend function "async" is incorrect because suspend functions are called synchronously.

Comment: Could you please show me how it would look like on my example? Do I need to wrap every single method in the "TestLibrary" in order to do so? Regarding async, you are right, it's not async as in Kotlin async{}, and that is a bit misleading. But I also wouldn't say they are called synchronously, traditionally I saw this used as executed in a single Thread in the Java / Reactive context. Sequentially would be probably bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with converting the suspend functions into Futures for use in Java, then you could do it like this.

You would need a CoroutineScope for running the coroutines that back up the Futures, and you would need a wrapper function for each suspend function that you want to use in Java.

You need to use the `kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8` library for this.

In this example, I believe I have used Kotlin and Java conventional naming for the functions. "Async" is never used in the names of suspend functions, but is typically used in function/method names that do not synchronously return a result. "Sync" is never used in function or method names.

```kotlin
class AsyncTestLibrary {
    private val testScope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()) + CoroutineName("TestScope")

    fun doActionA(){}
    suspend fun doActionB(): String { return "Test" }
    suspend fun doActionC(input: String) { println(input) }

    fun doActionBAsync() = testScope.future { doActionB() }
    fun doActionCAsync(input: String) = testScope.future { doActionC(input) }
}
```

```java
@Test
public void test(){
    testLibraryInstance.doActionA();
    testLibraryInstance.doActionBAsync()
        .thenCompose(value -> testLibraryInstance.doActionBAsync(value));
}
```

I haven't personally done unit tests involving futures, so you'll have to look up how to wait for and assert results.